# Run webdriver.io directly with chromedriver and not with selenium server

Tags: node.js, selenium, webdriver-io

I am trying to run selenium tests with webdriver.io in NodeJS but it wants to connect to a local instance of selenium-server. In Python it would just launch the local chromedriver.exe by giving it the path like so:

```
from selenium import webdriver
webdriver = webdriver.Chrome("C:/webdrivers/chromedriver.exe")
```

How can i use the same approach with webdriver.io? I don't want to install a selenium server on my local machine to be able to run the test suite.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution, there is a service called 'chromedriver' for wdio that runs the chromedriver directly without a proxy selenium-server.

https://github.com/atti187/wdio-chromedriver-service

I installed the required packages described in the link above and added the following to my wdio.conf.js file:

```
services: ['chromedriver'],
port: '9515',
path: '/',
chromeDriverArgs: ['--port=9515'],
chromeDriverLogs: './',
```

Comment: Should also note that you need to install 'chromedriver' itself via 'npm install chromedriver' in order to get this all working.